# Disjoint closed sets in subspace means closure is disjoint from set

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $Y$ be a subspace of a topological space $X$, and let $A$ and $B$ be two disjoint closed subsets of $Y$ in the subspace topology. Show that $\bar A \cap B=\varnothing$ and $A \cap \bar B=\varnothing$.

Attempt:Let $A$ and $B$ be two disjoint closed sets in $Y$. Then $A=\bar A \cap Y$,where $\bar A$ is the closure of $A$ in $X$. $B=\bar B \cap Y$, where $\bar B$ is the closure of $B$ in $X$.Then if $y \in \bar A,y \notin B$ since $X-\bar A$ is an open set containing $B$ disjoint from $A$. Similarly if $y \in \bar B$, $y \notin A$. Thus $\bar A \cap B=\varnothing$ and $A \cap \bar B=\varnothing$.

Comment: Unfortunately I think it is ok to assume if $A$ is closed in $Y$ $A=\bar A \cap Y$ for $\bar A$ the closure of $A$ in X, similarly for $B$, but I cannot understand why. Is this justified, if so what is the reason this is justified? Also, I am unsure whether it is correct to say that $X-\bar A$ contains $B$ and similarly for $X-\bar B$. Is this ok? If so why is this justified?

Comment: Just a somewhat relevant comment; you cannot expect to have a stronger general result in terms of disjointness in this particular setting. For example consider $X= \mathbb{R}$, $Y=[0,1) \cup (1,2]$, $A=[0,1)$ and $B=(1,2]$. Then both $A$ and $B$ are closed in $Y$ and of course disjoint. Clearly $\overline A \cap B=\varnothing$ and $A \cap \overline B=\varnothing$ but $\overline A \cap \overline B \neq \varnothing$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it’s correct.

Let $A$ be a relatively closed subset of $Y$. Then $A=Y\cap F$ for some $F$ that is closed in $X$, and $\operatorname{cl}_XA$ is the intersection of all closed subsets of $X$ that contain $A$, so $\operatorname{cl}_XA\subseteq F$, and therefore

$$A\subseteq Y\cap\operatorname{cl}_XA\subseteq Y\cap F=A\,,$$

which immediately implies that $A=Y\cap\operatorname{cl}_XA$.

Comment: One more question how can we be sure that $X- \bar A$ contains $B$, I feel like that implies $\bar A \cap B=\varnothing$ which is what the proof is supposed to show?

Comment: @DanielSchmidt: Since $A$ is closed in $Y$, every point of $(\operatorname{cl}_XA)\setminus A$ must be in $Y\setminus A$ and therefore not in $B$.

Answer (score 1):

It's OK, and you don't actually need that $\overline{A} \cap Y = A$, even though it's true:

$A$ closed in $Y$ just means there is *some* closed $C$ in $X$ so that $C \cap Y= A$. But then $B \subseteq X-C$ (or else any point in $B \cap C \subseteq Y \cap C=A$ contradicts the disjointness) and so every point of $B$ has an open neighbourhood (namely $X-C$) that is disjoint from $A$, so $x \in B \to x \notin \overline{A}$ showing in effect that $\overline{A} \cap B = \emptyset$. Doing the same argument for the closed $B$ shows $\overline{B} \cap A= \emptyset$ too.